# Where is InvalidChannelPermissions exception in pycord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, pycord

I have a bot that should join a voice channel via slash command. But then target voice channel reaches it's user limit, and command called by user, i'm getting discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception:
InvalidChannelPermissions: There are currently too many users in this channel. <2/2>
I know why is that, and i just need to make a handling of that error, but i didn't found that exception (InvalidChannelPermissions) anywhere in the docs of pycord or even in files.

I need to do something like:

```
if isinstance(error, InvalidChannelPermissions):
   # handle error
```

in my on_application_command_error event, but i can't find where is InvalidChannelPermissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the Pycord library, the `InvalidChannelPermissions` exception is not directly available. However, you can catch this exception by using the base `DiscordException` and checking for the error message. Here's an example:

```py
from discord.errors import DiscordException

@bot.event
async def on_application_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, DiscordException):
        if "InvalidChannelPermissions" in str(error) or "are currently too many users in this channel" in str(error):
            # handle error
```

Here, we catch the base DiscordException and check if the error message contains "InvalidChannelPermissions" or "are currently too many users in this channel". If it does, you can handle the error accordingly.